# Calculations from array values and operators

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning JavaScript and one of my challenges is to make a calculator without using eval() function.. So far I made inputs, input checking, etc. and I get an array that looks somewhat like this `numbers = ['-','1','+','2','*','3','+','(','5','/','2'comma','5',')','+','6'];` And since I'm still learning, I have no idea where to go from this.. How do i do the math on this string? How do i prioritize the calculations in ( ), *, / ? What technique should i use to solve this problem? I'm not looking for a ready to go answer, I want to write it myself, I need guidance on how to do this :)

Link to my current code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tmtLvfg8/29). so far I'm using the string to display the keys pressed.

```
var rezult = "0";
var numberJoin = [];

function skaicius(symbol) {
  numberJoin.push(symbol);
  secondTolast = numberJoin[numberJoin.length - 2];
  lastNumber = numberJoin[numberJoin.length - 1];
  symbolswithoutComma = numberJoin.toString();
  atsakymas = symbolswithoutComma.replace(/,/g, "");
  atsakymas = atsakymas.replace(/comma/g, ",");
  if (numberJoin[0] === "x" || numberJoin[0] === "+") {
    numberJoin = [];
  } else if ((symbol === "x" || symbol === "+" || symbol === "-") && (secondTolast === "x" || secondTolast === "+" || secondTolast === "-")) {
    numberJoin.splice(numberJoin.length - 2, numberJoin.length - 1);
    numberJoin.push(symbol);
  } else if (symbol === "delete") {
    numberJoin = [];
    rezult = "0";
    document.getElementById("rezult").innerHTML = rezult;
  } else if (symbol === "=") {
  } else {
    document.getElementById("rezult").innerHTML = atsakymas;
  }
}
```

EDIT: eval() and things like new function('return -1+2*3+(5/2,5)+6')() are a bit of cheats and since I'm learning, I'd like to try solving this problem without cheating :)

Comment: You need to share the code in the question...

Comment: working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tmtLvfg8/29/ - The scripts are by default added to a `onload` handler

Comment: Thank You for the comments and fixing my jsfiddle :)

Comment: Look for `(` in your array. If you find then look for `)`. after that make a new array from the values between `(` `)`. use recursive function to go deeper into the array and finding all `(` `)`. so at the end you ll ve small arrays. solve those first and replace the answer in the parent array, and then solve that. Once you are done with brackets then you ll simply have `+/-*` then look for ` \ ` in your array and solve the number around it and go on. Hope you get an idea from this.

Comment: You will have to look at notations like [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many well known algorithms which help in evaluating the expression.

using stack data structure you can push operators and operands in to array.
pop them in order form array to produce value for the given expression.

get some idea on infix,prefix and postfix notation of expression.

start with binary operations `+,-,%,*` and then enhance to incorporate parenthesis  `()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this, a collection of functions and a stack based iteration over the commands in a [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) style.

In the output you see the actual command and stack.

```js
var $ = {
        '===': function (b) { return function (a) { return a === b; }; },
        '+': function (b) { return function (a) { return a + b; }; },
        '-': function (b) { return function (a) { return a - b; }; },
        '1/x': function (a) { return 1 / a; },
    },
    commands = [3, 2, '+', 9, 4, '-', '==='],
    result = commands.reduce(function (stack, command) {
        var temp;
        if ($[command]) {
            temp = $[command];
            while (typeof temp === 'function') {
                temp = temp(stack.pop());
            }
            stack.push(temp);
        } else {
            stack.push(command);
        }
        document.write('<pre>' + command + ': ' + JSON.stringify(stack, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
        return stack;
    }, [])[0];

document.write(result);
```